# Play Framework Ebean models throws error when save() -ing (RuntimeException)

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I am looking for an answer for two days straight now and I cant seem to find an answer. So I have the following two independent Ebean models, while using the Play Framework.

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    public static final AtomicInteger seed = new AtomicInteger();

    @Id private final int id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String webpage;
    private String profileImgURL;
    private String rdfformat;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Language> languages;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Experience> experience;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Diploma> education;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Skill> skills;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<FriendRequest> friendRequests;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Friend> friends;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Recommendation> recommendations;

    public User(String name, String surname, String email, String city, String country,
        String webpage, String profileImgURL) {
        this.id = seed.incrementAndGet();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.webpage = webpage;
        this.profileImgURL = profileImgURL;
        this.languages = new ArrayList<>();
        this.experience = new ArrayList<>();
        this.education = new ArrayList<>();
        this.skills = new ArrayList<>();
        this.friendRequests = new ArrayList<>();
        this.friends = new ArrayList<>();
        this.recommendations = new ArrayList<>();
        this.rdfformat = "test";
    }

   public User() {
        this.id = seed.incrementAndGet();
        this.friends = new ArrayList<>();
        this.languages = new ArrayList<>();
        this.experience = new ArrayList<>();
        this.education = new ArrayList<>();
        this.skills = new ArrayList<>();
        this.friendRequests = new ArrayList<>();
        this.friends = new ArrayList<>();
        this.recommendations = new ArrayList<>();
   }

  public int getId() { return id; }
  public com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model getModel() {return model;}
  public String getRDFModel() {return rdfformat;}
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public String getSurname() { return surname; }
  public String getEmail() { return email; }
  public String getCity() { return city; }
  public String getCountry() { return country; }
  public String getWebpage() { return webpage; }
  @JsonProperty("profile_img_url")
  public String getProfileImgURL() { return profileImgURL; }
  public List<Language> getLanguages() { return languages; }
  public List<Experience> getExperience() { return experience; }
  public List<Diploma> getEducation() { return education; }
  public List<Skill> getSkills() { return skills; }
  public List<FriendRequest> getFriendRequests() { return friendRequests; }
  public List<Friend> getFriends() { return friends; }
  public List<Recommendation> getRecommendations() { return recommendations; }

  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
  public void setSurname(String surname) { this.surname = surname; }
  public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
  public void setCity(String city) { this.city = city; }
  public void setCountry(String country) { this.country = country; }
  public void setWebpage(String webpage) { this.webpage = webpage; }
  @JsonProperty("profile_img_url")
  public void setProfileImgURL(String profileImgURL) { this.profileImgURL = profileImgURL; }
  public void setLanguages(List<Language> languages) { this.languages = languages; }
  public void setExperience(List<Experience> experience) { this.experience = experience; }
  public void setEducation(List<Diploma> education) {   this.education = education; }
  public void setSkills(List<Skill> skills) { this.skills = skills; }
  public void setFriendRequests(List<FriendRequest> friendRequests) { this.friendRequests = friendRequests; }
  public void setFriends(List<Friend> friends) { this.friends = friends; }
  public void setRecommendations(List<Recommendation> recommendations) { this.recommendations = recommendations; }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Vacancy extends Model {

    public static final AtomicInteger seed = new AtomicInteger();

    @Id private final int vacId;

    private int authorId;
    private String title;
    private String location;
    private int months;
    private String salary;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Diploma> requiredDiplomas;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Experience> requiredExperience;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Skill> requiredSkills;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Language> requiredLanguages;

    public Vacancy(int userId, String title, String location, int months, String salary, String description) {
        this.vacId = seed.incrementAndGet();
        this.authorId = userId;
        this.title = title;
        this.location = location;
        this.months = months;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.description = description;
        this.requiredDiplomas = new ArrayList<>();
        this.requiredExperience = new ArrayList<>();
        this.requiredSkills = new ArrayList<>();
        this.requiredLanguages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Vacancy() {
        this.vacId = seed.incrementAndGet();
        this.requiredDiplomas = new ArrayList<>();
        this.requiredExperience = new ArrayList<>();
        this.requiredSkills = new ArrayList<>();
        this.requiredLanguages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getVacId() { return vacId; }
    public int getAuthorId() { return authorId; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public String getLocation() { return location; }
    public int getMonths() { return months; }
    public String getSalary() { return salary; }
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    public List<Diploma> getRequiredDiplomas() { return requiredDiplomas; }
    public List<Experience> getRequiredExperience() { return requiredExperience; }
    public List<Skill> getRequiredSkills() { return requiredSkills; }
    public List<Language> getRequiredLanguages() { return requiredLanguages; }

    public void setAuthorId(int userId) { this.authorId = userId; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
    public void setLocation(String location) { this.location = location; }
    public void setMonths(int months) { this.months = months; }
    public void setSalary(String salary) { this.salary = salary; }
    public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }
    public void setRequiredDiplomas(List<Diploma> requiredDiplomas) { this.requiredDiplomas = requiredDiplomas; }
    public void setRequiredExperience(List<Experience> requiredExperience) { this.requiredExperience = requiredExperience; }
    public void setRequiredSkills(List<Skill> requiredSkills) { this.requiredSkills = requiredSkills; }
    public void setRequiredLanguages(List<Language> requiredLanguages) { this.requiredLanguages = requiredLanguages; }
}
```

Both models have an @Id, and have their own written getter. Now in my Application Controller I have this function called populate(), which cleans the database and fills it with data. The function below:

```
public static Result populate() throws ParseException {

    cleanup();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    // USER 2
    User user2 = new User("John", "Doe", "john.doe@gmoil.com", "London", "United Kingdom", "www.johndoe.com", "");
    user2.addLanguage(new Language("english",4));
    user2.save();

    // VACANCY 1
    Vacancy vacancy1 = new Vacancy(5, "Software Developer", "London, UK", 24, "60-80K", "Program things");
    vacancy1.addRequiredDiploma(new Diploma("Bachelor's degree", "Computer Science"));
    vacancy1.addRequiredExperience(new Experience("Software Developer", 3));
    vacancy1.addRequiredSkill(new Skill("Java", 4));
    vacancy1.addRequiredLanguage(new Language("english", 4));
    vacancy1.save(); // ERROR HERE

    return ok("Users added! (" + User.find().findRowCount() + ")\nVacancies added! (" + Vacancy.find().findRowCount() + ")\n");
}
```

Now when I try to call populate, I get the following error message on the line of vacacancy1.save() :

```
 [RuntimeException: get id on [models.User] type[models.Vacancy] threw error.]
```

Keeping in mind that everything works perfectly when there's only one model (User). To what I understand it has something to do with the id's of the models, but I cant figure out what. I have already tried several things, like renaming them differently, giving them the same name, provide getters for the id's in the OneToMany models. Anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance.

EDIT1: I figured out what caused the error, but I have not yet found a solution to solve it. It's basically because I'm using some Models (the lists) in both User and Vacancy and my guess is therefore when calling those models it does not know by which (User or Vacancy) it belongs? I'm not sure though, but the error disappeared when I removed the lists from Vacancy.

Comment: Can you please show us the contructors in the model classes? thank you :) Do you set a id for user2 and vacancy1? In the constructors in the populate() method, you didn't set any id (in vacancy1 only the authorid) as I can see.

Comment: I have added the constructors and getters/setters, I always give the models an id, by using AtomicSeed. I have never experienced a problem with this, so my guess is this is okay.

Comment: Ah okay I understand. Have you tried to debug it and looked if there really is an id set for the objects?

Comment: I just did a couple of times, and they both have and id, which are different all the time.